# calling different jsp files from same java class

Tags: jsp

I am creating a simple web-app which has a jsp login page. after validating the credentials i get the parameters using a servlet's doPost method. Now i pass these values to a simple java class(not servlet) and then using JDBC techniques i return a string which says **correct password/wrong password/invalid username** back to the servlet. now from the servlet i call a jsp which will print the string on the screen.

Its working fine. now i would like to call 3 jsp's from my java class itself. eg, in the if() block for correct password id like to call a jsp called correct.jsp which already has the code to print "correct password" on the screen. likewise.

Can you suggest me how to call jsp from java file.i just need to call the jsp and load it. no need of doing any modification with the jsp file.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is not the right approach. You're tight-coupling your Java database access class with JSP/Servlet APIs. Your Java database access class should return a sensible/reuseable result and/or throw a sensible exception. You should be doing this in the servlet instead.

E.g.

```
try {
    User user = userService.find(username, password);

    if (user == null) {
        response.sendRedirect("wronglogin.jsp");
    } else {
        request.getSession().setAttribute("user", user);
        response.sendRedirect("correctlogin.jsp");
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    response.sendRedirect("databaseerror.jsp");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

It would by the way also be far much easier if you use one and same JSP which displays the error message conditionally instead of displaying a hardcoded message and if necessary let the servletcontainer's default error page mechanmism handle the exception based on `<error-page>` in `web.xml`. It would also be far much more user friendly if you display the message straight in the same JSP page where the login form sits so that the enduser don't need to navigate back to the login form.

E.g.

```
try {
    User user = userService.find(username, password);

    if (user == null) {
        request.setAttribute("message", "Login failed, unknown user");
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/login.jsp").forward(request, response);
    } else {
        request.getSession().setAttribute("user", user);
        response.sendRedirect("correctlogin.jsp");
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    throw new ServletException("Database error!", e);
}
```

#### See also:

- [Our servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) - The hello world example also covers validation